# text field hyper links are not exported to ppt in jasperreport

Tags: hyperlink, jasper-reports

I have a jasper report where the text fields are having hyper links to share point documents.The links work just fine in report and in other export formats such as excel and pdf but when exported to pptx , only the text fields are exported but not the links.
FYI -- the jasper reports version is 5.6.1
Plz help if anyone has a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested it (with `hyperlinkType="Reference"`) and can not find any problems.

This is how I export to `pptx`

```
JRPptxExporter exporter = new JRPptxExporter();
File outputFile = new File("test.pptx");
exporter.setExporterInput(new SimpleExporterInput(print));
exporter.setExporterOutput(new SimpleOutputStreamExporterOutput(outputFile));
SimplePptxReportConfiguration configuration = new SimplePptxReportConfiguration();
configuration.setIgnoreHyperlink(false);
exporter.setConfiguration(configuration);
exporter.exportReport();
```

Naturally the hyper link does **not work** if your are in **design mode** (since its design mode) you need to switch to **presentation mode**.

If you still have problems please post jrxml related to your `textField` definition and your code for exporting to pptx.

Comment: ,Thank you so much. Though i have set the ignorehyperlink property to false, I never knew that the links work in presentation mode only.